# Make directive use parent scope?

Tags: angularjs

I made an include directive like thus:

```
Log.directive 'logList', () ->
    return {
        restrict: 'E'
        scope:
            type: '='
        templateUrl: "/partials/log"
    }
```

I'm including it twice on the page, and would like both to use the root scope where they're included. Ever since putting this duplicate HTML in an include, I have to do messy things in it like $parent.$parent.something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS will create an *isolated scope* whenever you specify anything in the *scope field* of the *directive declaration*. As the name suggest, this isolated scope does not inherit from the parent scope and thus cannot access parent scope values directly.

However, depending on the situation there are multiple ways to access parent scope properties, without using the error prone *$parent*.

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/54WEuyX2jcJiAOEt9Cd4?p=preview).

For instance by observing the value of the attribute ourself we don't need to create an isolated scope and thus we can access all container scope properties:

```
myApp.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  $scope.demo = { myValue: "Shared scope value" };
});

myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {

  return {
    template: '<div>{{ demo.myValue }}</div>',
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      $attrs.$observe('type', function(value) {
        $element.removeClass();
        $element.addClass('alert alert-' + value);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

If you really need a two way binding, which allows you to update the value from within the directive, you can make use of the [$parse service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24parse). But in most cases you don't need this because you've access to the scope anyway:

```
myApp.directive('myTwoWayDirective', function() {

  return {
    template: '<div>{{ demo.myValue }}' +
                '<select class="pull-right" ' +
                         'ng-model="demo.twoWayType" ' +
                         'ng-options="type for type in demo.types">' +
                '<select>' +
              '</div>',
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      $scope.$watch('demo.twoWayType', function(value) {
        $element.removeClass();
        $element.addClass('alert alert-' + value);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Edit:

New plunker to demonstrate how to [share data across angular components](http://plnkr.co/edit/bNJtOP?p=preview)
and
an additional plunker which might give some more [insight on directive scopes](http://plnkr.co/edit/eS45IY?p=preview).

Comment: How would this let me pass a unique argument into each directive? Right now I'm passing in a different type so in the include I can do: div.row(ng-repeat="log in $parent[type] | prepare_log | orderBy: 'log.created'")

Comment: Just make use of $observe method from the attrs argument, assign it's value to the scope of the directive and that expression will work. But(**!!**) ... you should always try to avoid the use of $parent and there's most certainly no need to hack in a shared scope, compile an extra template on each link and re-link that template with the shared scope :) I'll add a new plunker.

Comment: My understand of what I needed and exactly what I was asking has increased as I look over angular's include source, and your and daiwei's stuff. I think I figured out exactly what I need, but I'd appreciate it if you could give me your opinion on the solution I posted.

Answer (score 0):

This works. I'm sure it can be done better though. This gets me includes that behave exactly as if they were written inline to the page, and also can have some unique changes to them via the templateReplace argument.

```
Log.directive 'logList', ($compile, $templateCache, $http) ->
    return {
        restrict: 'E'
        compile: (element, attr) ->
            return (scope, $element, $attr, ctrl) ->
                $http.get('/partials/log', {cache: $templateCache}).success (template) ->
                    template_replace = if $attr.templatereplace then $attr.templatereplace.split(',') else null
                    angular.forEach template_replace, (value, key) ->
                        template = template.replace '%replace%', value

                    content = $compile(template)(scope)
                    $element.html('')
                    $element.append(content)                
    }
```

Here's an example of the template I'm using, that just needs 1 teeny change, but is otherwise identical in both columns of my app:

```
div.row(ng-repeat="log in %replace% | prepare_log | orderBy: 'log.created'")
    div.log-wrapper(ng-class="log.level")
        a.pin(title="Pin this log message", ng-click="pin($index, %replace%)")
```

And here's my main template that implements the directive:

```
div.columns.small-6
    log-list(templateReplace="logs,1")

div.columns.small-6
    log-list(templateReplace="pinned,0")
```

Edit:

What I actually ended up doing:

```
    div.columns.small-6
        div.row(ng-repeat="log in logs | prepare_log | orderBy: 'log.created'", ng-init="pin_or_unpin=1")
            ng-include(src="'/partials/log'")
```

Partial:

```
div.log-wrapper(ng-class="log.level")
    a.pin(title="Pin this log message", ng-click="pin($index, pin_or_unpin)")
```

Comment: If it works; it works ... but there's no need to search and replace the templatecache and recompile it. Angular can do all of this for you in a much cleaner and efficient way. For example the %replace% placeholder could be a variable from the scope (and maybe supplied to the directive by an attribute). 

I've added a [new plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bNJtOP?p=preview) to the answer, maybe that will give you some more insight.

Comment: That plunker is great, and demonstrates exactly what I needed. It turns out I was making this much harder than it needed to be. When I had the ng-repeat inside the include I lost the the scope and had to do $parent, $parent.$parent, etc. When I moved the ng-repeat outside the include, it all worked well and let me do a simple ng-init to set my custom values for the include. Thanks for helping me through this.

Answer (score -1):

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/mgiYWP

For directive, even they are from the save constructor, there is no easy way to automatically find the common scope of both directive. But you can share the same variable before `return` statements.

```
app.directive('logList', function($compile, $templateCache) {

  var sharedScope;

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    // scope: {
    //   type: '='
    // },
    templateUrl: "log.html",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      // create shared isolated scope if not defined yet
      if (typeof sharedScope === 'undefined') {
        sharedScope = scope.$new(true);

        // manual bi-directional binding for type attribute
        sharedScope.$watch(function() {
          return scope.$eval(attrs.type);
        }, function(val) {
          sharedScope.type = val;
        });
      }

      // recompile directive DOM content to sharedScope
      var template = $templateCache.get('log.html')[1];
      var newContent = $compile(template)(sharedScope);

      element.html('');
      element.append(newContent);
    }
  };

});
```

This should give a shared isolated scope to all `logList` directive, but because you share a isolated scope, you can only bi-directional bind the `type` attribute from the directive that is instantiated first.

Comment: They're actually included in the same controller, so they already share a parent scope. What I would like to do is have them be included "transparently" and behave as if I'd put them directly in the template, instead of in their own inherited scope.

Comment: @Joren I just updated the answer, I don't know if this is what you want.

Comment: This looks like it might work. Could I $compile the directive with the main $scope of my module, instead of a new shared scope?

Comment: @Joren, if you do not define `scope` property on directive, the directive will not create a new scope, so it will share the scope with parent element. If you want to interpret attribute values for the directive, use `var type = $scope.$eval(attrs.type)` to evaluate type attribute on scope.

Comment: I think I almost have this working, could you elaborate on the $eval thing?